# Intel Pin Tool on Linux 4.0

Tags: linux, intel, instrumentation

I am getting "E: 4.0 is not a supported Linux release" when I try and run ManualExamples on my Linux machine.

Terminal Output

```
pin/source/tools/ManualExamples$ ../../../pin -t obj-intel64/inscount0.so -- /bin/ls
E: 4.0 is not a supported linux release
```

Does pin not support latest linux kernel?

Thanks! Manish

Answer (score 2):

Pin 3.0 is now available, and is compatible with Linux Kernels 4.0 or higher.

However, chances are your existing Pintool (i.e. Pin 2.x compatible)  won't work with Pin 3.0 since it forces you to use PinCRT and doesn't let you link your tool with outside libraries.

Still, there is a workaround for using Pin 2.x on kernels 4.0 or higher. Just use `-injection child` or `-injection parent` with your Pintool. For some reason Pin doesn't seem to care which kernel version you are running in these cases.

```
pin_kit$ uname -a
Linux 4.8.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 11 14:03:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

pin_kit$ ./pin -t source/tools/ManualExamples/obj-intel64/inscount0.so -- /bin/ls
E:4.8 is not a supported linux release

pin_kit$ ./pin -injection child -t source/tools/ManualExamples/obj-intel64/inscount0.so -- /bin/ls
doc  extras  ia32  inscount.out  intel64  LICENSE  pin  pin.log  pin.sh  README  redist.txt  source

pin_kit$ ./pin -injection parent -t source/tools/ManualExamples/obj-intel64/inscount0.so -- /bin/ls
doc  extras  ia32  inscount.out  intel64  LICENSE  pin  pin.log  pin.sh  README  redist.txt  source
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not yet a Pin release available that supports Linux kernels 4.0 or higher.

You could try [DynamoRIO](http://dynamorio.org) instead:

```
$ cd DynamoRIO-Linux-6.1.0-2
$ bin64/drrun -c samples/bin64/libinscount.so -- /bin/ls
Client inscount is running
ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS  bin64  docs       drmemory   ext      lib32  License.txt  README   tools
bin32             cmake  drcov.out  dynamorio  include  lib64  logs         samples
Instrumentation results: 506331 instructions executed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the -ifeellucky option. It works for me in 4.5 kernel.